# How to add output "non_assigned" when there is no match in grep?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

When I run a command (COMMAND) on one line of my input file (input.txt) I get an associated result where only one line is interesting, always starting by the world phylum.

For instance:

```
superkingdom    2759    Eukaryota
clade   554915  Amoebozoa
phylum  555280  Discosea
order   313555  Himatismenida
family  313556  Cochliopodiidae
```

So I run :

```
for p in $(cat input.txt) 
    do COMMAND $p | grep "\bphylum\b" >> results.txt
done
```

In order  to have in my file result.txt all the lines like :

```
phylum  555280  Discosea
```

However there is sometimes no results with grep (there is no line starting with phylum), and it adds no line to results.txt. I would like for these specific cases add some line with "0" or "non assigned" for instance (so each line of input.txt matches results.txt).

```
clade   2696291 Ochrophyta
class   5747    Eustigmatophyceae
order   425074  Eustigmatales
family  425072  Monodopsidaceae
```

I have tried adding | awk print '{print $0"non_assigned"}' , unsuccesfully.

Do you have any ideas to help me ? A member advices me to use awk '/phylum/{print $0}!/phylum/{print "non_assigned";exit} but i get as output "non_assigned" even if the phylum result is present.

Comment: `awk '/phylum/{print $0}!/phylum/{print "non_assigned"}'`

Comment: unfortunately when I use your command I still have nothing as output

Comment: you need to remove `grep` and only use `awk`

Comment: Ok my bad ! Hmm now I get multiple lines all "non_assigned" except the eventually one with "phylum 200 1212"

Comment: `awk '/phylum/{print $0}!/phylum/{print "non_assigned";exit}'`

Comment: What shell/programming language is that meant to be in the first place?  I can't think of anything in which `for p in (input.txt) do COMMAND $p` is valid syntax ...

Comment: @P... mmh no I get "non_assigned" even if there is the line phylum in the output

Comment: @tink it's a bash scrip (i forget the done and the indentation)

Comment: I'm not sure why this got closed, but this will do the job: `for p in $(<input.txt);
do (COMMAND $p | grep -w "phylum") || echo "non_assigned";
done >> results.txt`  Notice that the redirection has been moved to after the `done`; it might be better to use `>` rather than `>>` now.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JonathanLeffler it works perfectly !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
for p in $(<input.txt)
do
    (COMMAND $p | grep -w "phylum") || echo "non_assigned"
done >> results.txt
```

This runs the command and the `grep` in a subshell.  If the `grep` finds 'phylum', the RHS of the `||` is not run; if 'phylum' is not found, the `echo` is executed to output a suitable marker.

Notice that the redirection has been moved to after the `done`; it might be better to use `>` rather than `>>` now.

Beware the [`set`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin) option `-o pipefail` — if the command can fail, you might need to use `set +o pipefail`.  However, it is disabled by default, so you'll probably be OK.