# How to add a line result "non_assigned" when no match using awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

When I run a command (COMMAND) on one line of my input file (input.txt) I get an associated result where only one line is interesting, always starting by the world phylum.

For instance:

```
superkingdom    2759    Eukaryota
clade   554915  Amoebozoa
phylum  555280  Discosea
order   313555  Himatismenida
family  313556  Cochliopodiidae
```

So I run :

```
for p in $(cat input.txt)
    do COMMAND $p | grep "\bphylum\b" >> results.txt
done
```

In order to have in my file result.txt all the lines like :

```
phylum  555280  Discosea
```

However there is sometimes no results with grep (there is no line starting with phylum), and it adds no line to results.txt. I would like for these specific cases add some line with "0" or "non assigned" for instance (so each line of input.txt matches results.txt).

```
clade   2696291 Ochrophyta
class   5747    Eustigmatophyceae
order   425074  Eustigmatales
family  425072  Monodopsidaceae
```

I have tried adding | awk print '{print $0"non_assigned"}' , unsuccesfully.

Do you have any ideas to help me ? A member advices me to use awk '/phylum/{print $0}!/phylum/{print "non_assigned";exit} but i get as output "non_assigned" even if the phylum result is present.

Comment: Your identical question has been closed for a reason. Please fix the reason it was closed and do not duplicate your post. [How to add output "non\_assigned" when there is no match in grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454736/how-to-add-output-non-assigned-when-there-is-no-match-in-grep)

Comment: I wonder why was it closed. It had sample data, expected output and code that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?:

```
$ grep phylum file || echo "non assigned"
```

Output when *phylum* found in file:

```
phylum  555280  Discosea
```

and when not found:

```
non assigned
```

Same in awk:

```
$ awk '/phylum/&&found=1;END{if(!found)print "non assigned"}'
```